# Prevent publishing to public NuGet gallery

Tags: nuget

We're using NuGet to package our internal dependencies. We're setting up a private NuGet repository for these.

However, I'm concerned that someone might accidentally publish one of our packages to the public NuGet repository.

Can I prevent this?

Answer (score 2):

You can define `NuGet.config` file with `DefaultPushSource` value referencing your internal NuGet Gallery instance. Put the config file next to your internal packages `nuspec` files.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <config>
    <add key="DefaultPushSource" value="https://nuget.example.com" />
  </config>
</configuration>
```

> In general the NuGet.config file closest to the folder nuget.exe runs from wins, the section below walks through the details.
>
> NuGet first loads NuGet.config from the default location, then loads any file named NuGet.config starting from the root of the current drive and ending in the current directory.
>
> [Chaining multiple configuration files](https://docs.nuget.org/consume/nuget-config-file#chaining-multiple-configuration-files)
>
> The NuGet Config Defaults file also allows specification of the Default Push Source. This will be the default push source if one is not provided in the command line argument of nuget.exe. Without a default push source specifid in the NuGet Config Defaults file, nuget.org is the default nuget.exe push source. Using the new configuration though, administrators can change the default push source to an internal package soure. This will help prevent accidental publishing of packages to nuget.org.
>
> [Default NuGet.exe Push Source](https://docs.nuget.org/consume/nuget-config-defaults#sample-nugetdefaults.config)

Comment: Unfortunately this doesnt seem to work with newer clients ^3.0

Answer (score -3):

No, you can't. And you needn't.

Accidentally in the case when someone has published nuget package to a wrong server means that someone has **the same** API Key for several nuget servers (let's say your local gallery and nuget.org). The probability of that case is the same that `Guid.NewGuid()` will generate two equal GUIDs. One for your local nuget server and second for someone else to publish package to public nuget server.

Or accidentally in reality means "accidentally". There is no solution.

Comment: This also could mean that the API key was stored using the SetApiKey command.

Comment: This answer is not correct.  You're ignoring the setapikey command.